# What is netbeans doing now?

Tags: netbeans

This is getting tedious. I created a test project, simple java hello, to test a problem I have in another project. Having created the project, I could run it and build it to a jar.

Then I added some ivy stuff and tried a build which did not work. The ivy stuff consisted of ivy.xml ivysettings.xml and 2 tasks added to the otherwise default netbeans build.xml.

So then I removed the ivy files and the ivy sections from build.xml. I then did a diff on that and the previous unedited build.xml file and they are identical.

So now why after a clean build do I get this error?

```
/home/tester/WORKSPACE/NetBeans/Foo/nbproject/build-impl.xml:63: Source resource does not exist: /home/tester/WORKSPACE/NetBeans/Foo/lib/nblibraries.properties
```

Correct that file does not exist and it does not exist in any other project I have access to whether they use ivy or not.

I have reset everything I did yet Netbeans cannot continue. I have tried to work out how the hell nb actually builds a project but got lost. Just don't know what to say.

I guess nb and myself differ on what clean actually means and also on whether a task should be able to produce exact same results everytime given the same input, something that nb does not seem to be able to do. That or it cannot recover from the real world or their documentation just hides the useful information like how to reset a project.

I'm assuming there is some nb state that needs to be cleaned up manually but have no idea where to start. Any ideas please?

Comment: This sounds like Ivy is still running (and is doing its job).  Ivy thinks your project should have that depedency.  Can you find out where in the project this dependency exists?

Comment: There is no dependency. The project consists of a simple hello world main, nothing else. It uses nothing.

Answer (score 1):

@Tim Biegeleisen, your comment got me thinking.

I shut down/restarted netbeans then tried the build again and it worked. So it seems that ivy is still running inside netbeans and has some form of state for my project that it will not release. I'll have to dig around to see if there is a way to reset ivy state without restarting nb but this whole process is turning in to a very tedious onerous task. I seem to be spending more time on the dev tools than I am on solving my coding tasks.

So the solution/workaround to my problem seems to be to restart netbeans to clear ivy state.

Comment: This was my hunch after reading your original problem.  And yes, I also have spent a ton of time on dev tool stuff.  But once you resolve the setbacks, you will hopefully be able to code your project quickly.

Comment: Yeah, the project itself is coded. I am just having horrendous problems delivering it. Thanks for the hunch.